# Show/Hide & Change CSS functions are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsfiddle

After a form is submitted to an `<Iframe>` target on the page, and after the `<iframe>` finishes loading, there is 1 `<div>` that is suppose to hide, 2 `<div>` that need to show and 2 CSS changes that are all suppose to trigger, but they are not.

This is a fiddle of the page:
http://jsfiddle.net/mikeef74/gzSDH/17/

This is how I currently have the script:

```
var submit_hit = false;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#iframe1').on('load', function () {
        $('#loader1').hide();
        if (submit_hit) {
            $('#form_container').hide();
            $('#mydivhide1, #mydivhide2').show();
            $('body').css("background-image", "url(images/previewbg7.jpg)");
            $('body').css("overflow-y", "auto");
        }
    }
});

$("#form_710370").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $("#loader1").show();
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Your jsfiddle points at JQuery...is that normal ??

Comment: @PSL I just wanted a page to display something since the site I am developing is local on my machine. It was the first thign that popped in my head :)

Comment: you need to clarify your question , what div should be hidden and what div should be shown ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this the full code you are not making submit_hit to true, i think its need to set true  before form.submit() so the js for div1/div2 execute.

```
 $("#loader1").show();
   submit_hit = true;
  form.submit();
```

[JSfiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/gzSDH/19/)